# Is there a “not in” operator in JavaScript for checking object properties?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, operators

Is there any sort of "not in" operator in JavaScript to check if a property does not exist in an object? I couldn’t find anything about this around Google or Stack Overflow. Here’s a small snippet of code I’m working on where I need this kind of functionality:

```
var tutorTimes = {};

$(checked).each(function(idx){
  id = $(this).attr('class');

  if(id in tutorTimes){}
  else{
    //Rest of my logic will go here
  }
});
```

As you can see, I’d be putting everything into the `else` statement. It seems wrong to me to set up an `if`–`else` statement just to use the `else` portion.

Comment: I think you might want `var id = ...` in your function.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

> It seems wrong to me to set up an if/else statement just to use the else portion...

Just negate your condition, and you'll get the `else` logic inside the `if`:

```
if (!(id in tutorTimes)) { ... }
```

Comment: This style also fixes the JSHint "Confusing use of '!'" warning you'd get if you did if `( ! somekey in someobj )`

Comment: Please note that **in** searches for the property name **anywhere** in the prototype chain. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12573605/36866) for more details.

Comment: I understand this is currently the best solution, but does anyone else agree that this is kinda ugly?

Comment: If it's ugly then just wrap it in a function and give it a beautiful name  ```let keyExists = (key, obj) => key in obj```

Comment: I totally agree. Indeed my naming skills could be improved too . ```let hasProperty``` "looks" better

Comment: @mikemaccana, I'm pretty sure that's because (! somekey in someobj) becomes (false in someobj).

Answer (score 86):

Personally I find

```
if (id in tutorTimes === false) { ... }
```

easier to read than

```
if (!(id in tutorTimes)) { ... }
```

but both will work.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the more direct version too. The other is fine but more chars to read and consider. "if something is false" is easy to understand

Answer (score 47):

As already said by Jordão, just negate it:

```
if (!(id in tutorTimes)) { ... }
```

Note: The above test if tutorTimes has a property with the name specified in id, **anywhere** in the prototype chain. For example `"valueOf" in tutorTimes` returns *true* because it is defined in *Object.prototype*.

If you want to test if a property doesn't exist in the current object, use hasOwnProperty:

```
if (!tutorTimes.hasOwnProperty(id)) { ... }
```

Or if you might have a key that is *hasOwnPropery* you can use this:

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(tutorTimes,id)) { ... }
```

If your environment supports ECMA-292 from July 2022, you can use the   convenient alternative to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` [Object.hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn):

```
if (!Object.hasOwn(tutorTimes,id)) { ... }
```

Comment: Is it any *safer* to wrap the key in quotes and use `if(!tutorTimes.hasOwnProperty('id')) ...`?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour `id` is an variable that could have any value, `'id'` is a string with the two letters **i** and **d**, so `hasOwnProperty(id)` checks if the property specified in the variable *id* exists, and `hasOwnProperty('id')` checks if there is a property named id.

Answer (score 16):

Two quick possibilities:

```
if(!('foo' in myObj)) { ... }
```

or

```
if(myObj['foo'] === undefined) { ... }
```

Comment: Use `'undefined' === typeof xxx` instead. `undefined` is not a reserved word and is actually a global variable that can be overwritten (leading to hard to find bugs)

Comment: @hippietrail doesn't work...the parens are required after the "!" and around the `'foo' in myObj)`

Comment: `myObj['foo']` could exist as a property and simply be set to `undefined` (i.e., with the statement `myObj.foo = undefined`). If you really want to see if the property itself doesn't exist, you need the `!('foo' in myObj)` notation.

Comment: For the performance conscious among us, checking for `myObj.foo === undefined` is much faster (albeit potentially dangerous): [jsperf.com/not-in-vs-is-undefined](https://jsperf.com/not-in-vs-is-undefined).

Comment: @hugomg I don't think that is a very good argument for not using `=== undefined`. Lots of things can break if people abuse a programming language by doing things like, for example, overwriting `undefined` in JavaScript. Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/javascript-how-dangerous-is-it-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritten

Comment: In 2011 @hugomg was right that undefined was a variable that could be overwritten with another value. That was changed in ECMA-262 5.1 Edition from June 2011.

Comment: You can overwrite a lot of stuff in Javascript.  If someone redefines undefined, just fire them.... :)

Answer (score 3):

you can set the condition to be false

```
if ((id in tutorTimes === false)) { ... }
```

Comment: You don't need the inner parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

not very readable but a quick short hand could be:

```
if (id in tutorTimes ^ 1) { ... }
```

when doing operation with XOR, `false` and `true` got converted into `0` and `1` respectively. hence that reverse the result.