# How do I say 'not in' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript code as follows:

```
addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);    
if (81 in keysDown){
    doThisFunction() //q
}
```

doThisFunction will be called when I press the q button on the keyboard.
I found the line "81 in keysDown" to be quite interesting.

I was wondering if there was a way to say "if 81 is NOT in keysDown" so that I can detect a moment when q has been let go or when q is not pressed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(!keysDown[81])`

Comment: `!` is "not", `in` is "in", `!(... in ...)` is "not in". Is nesting so hard?

Comment: In this particular case it looks like that you should do just  `if(keysDown['81'])` and `if(!keysDown['81'])`.

Answer (score 11):

Just use the [negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)):

```
if (!(81 in keydown)) …
```

Notice you need the additional [grouping parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) to get the desired operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can by wrapping the whole conditional in parentheses and negating it, like so:

```
if(!(81 in keysDown)) {
    doThisFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the index:

```
if(keysDown.indexOf(81) < 0){
    //code
}
```

Or [if it is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972446/javascript-not-in-operator-for-checking-object-properties):

```
if (!(num in keysDown)) { ... }
```