# Is there " if .. not in .." in Javascript? I use it in Python but not sure if Javascript has the similar syntax

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop, for-in-loop

This function should remove the vowels in string and return string without vowels

```
function removeVowels(string) {
    var newstring = '';
    var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    for ( i in string) {
        if ( i.toLowerCase() not in vowels) { // I know this is wrong but is anything I can use instead of "not in" in JS?
            continue
        } else {
            newstring += i
        }
    }
    return newstring;
}
```

Comment: Be careful! The `in` operator doesn't work the same way in JS as it does in Python. It searches for *properties in objects*, and doesn't work as a generalized "containment" operator. (and no, there is no `not in `operator)

Comment: To invert a test in javascript, use ```if (!(condition))```. Your question is covered here in [Is there a “not in” operator in JavaScript for checking object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972446/is-there-a-not-in-operator-in-javascript-for-checking-object-properties)

Comment: Also very important: `for ( i in string)` **does not work the same way in JS as it does in Python**. You'd need to use `for (i of string)`... you really should take the time to learn Javascript for-loops on their own terms

Comment: You also need to declare the iterated variable `for (let i of string) {...`

Comment: @pilchard well, in strict mode :)

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/in_operator_no_object) to clear up a common confusion about the `in` operator in JS. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) vs [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for the difference between `for of` and `for in` in JS

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have a `not` keyword. Instead, it has a `!` for whenever you want to use not.
JS's `in` is NOT the same as python's `in`. JS uses it for indexes, and if you want the character at the index, you should use `of`.

I have also made some minor tweaks here and there like not using var and removing the continue statements.

```js
function removeVowels(string) {
    // Instead of using var here, use let and const.
    let newString = '';
    const vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    // Loop through every character of string
    for (const char of string) {
        // Instead of the continue that you used, you can just simply check if the vowels array includes the specific character.
        if (!vowels.includes(char.toLowerCase())) {
            // This just appends the character to the new string variable
            newString += char;
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
console.log(removeVowels('This string will not have any vowels in it.'));
```

Comment: Thank you! this's really helpful

Comment: Marking the answer as right would help me a lot :)